# How to use for loop in lamba and map?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe **df** that has a column **tags** . Each element of the row **tags** is a **list of dictionary** and looks like this:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "new",
        "name": "new",
        "slug": null,
        "type": "HashTag",
        "endIndex": 0,
        "startIndex": 0
    },
    {
        "id": "1234",
        "name": "abc ltd.",
        "slug": "5678",
        "type": "StockTag",
        "endIndex": 0,
        "startIndex": 0
    }
]
```

The list can have any number of elements.

I want to filter the dataframe **df** for rows where any element of the **tags** column has the **type can be either StockTag or UserTag**

I was able to check if the first element of the list has the **type: StockTag** as follows

```python
df[df['tags'].map(lambda d: d[0]['type'] == 'StockTag')]
```

I am unable to check for other elements. Instead of checking only the **first(index=0) element**, I want to iterate through all the elements and check.

Any help on this?

Comment: That is not a lsit of dictionaries. I'm pretty sure you have a string which is valid JSON

Comment: In any case, you could use a comprehension in your lambda, something like `df['tags'].map(lambda ds: any(d['type'] == 'StockTag' for d in ds)` but why do you have to use a lambda expression? Just use a regular function defintion

Comment: Will that work? `df[df['tags'].map(lambda d: all(e['type'] == 'StockTag' for e in d))]`

Comment: Yes it is actually json. However, this data is fetched from DB so can't this be treated as dictionary?
Also, I edited the question : the type can be either stocktag or post tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm supposing, you have dataframe like this:

```
        data                                               tags
0  some_data  [{'id': 'new', 'name': 'new', 'slug': None, 't...
```

Where `tags` column contains list of dictionaries.

Then you can use **`any()`** to search the `tags` column for `StockTag` type:

```
print(df[df["tags"].apply(lambda x: any(d["type"] == "StockTag" for d in x))])
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to check for the type to be either StockTag or UserTag.. can I use an```or``` ? I tried with ```or``` but the answer was not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @dipanjana You can do `df[df["tags"].apply(lambda x: any(d["type"] in ("StockTag", "UserTag") for d in x))]`